# Get all products that belong to a category or parent-n category

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, categories, product

I have a Category structure like so:

```
- Cars
  - 4 Door
    - Sedan
    - SUV
  - 2 Door
    - Sports
    - Race
```

A Product can belong_to a single Category, and given the way I set up the UI, the user can only select from a leaf node.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subcategories, class_name: 'Category', foreign_key: 'parent_id', dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :parent_category, class_name: 'Category'
  has_many :products
end
```

Now, when they are browsing around, I can list products from the Sedan category, no problem. But what about when they click Cars, it should show all products in 4 Door (Sedan, SUV) and 2 Door (Sports, Race) since they are child categories.

Or when they click on 4 Door, it should list all products in Sedan *and* SUV. Does that make sense?

How can I get all products that are inside a given category?

Comment: Have you had a go at trying different things in the rails console? Can you show us the code you have tried? and the results you are expecting v what you are getting?

Comment: `@category.products` only pulls products that are in that category and not in the subcategories as well.

Comment: and what are the results you're getting when you try this in rails console?

Comment: It's right there in my previous comment: "only pulls products that are in that category and not in the subcategories as well."

Comment: no, the *actual results*, not a description of the result... also - don't get annoyed at me for asking you to clarify your question...

Comment: I would strongly recommend you using https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set .

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use recursion to get them, in a manner like:

```
def get_products(category)
    products = category.products.to_a
    category.subcategories.each do |sub|
      products << get_products(sub)
    end

    products
end
```

It should belong in `Category` model

Comment: For some reason when I run this, all of the products in the collection have `category_id` set to the root parent category id. The database records are actually updated!

Comment: @Serg I have fixed code, I put whole relation into `products` variable hence the effect. Update is that `to_a` call that will remove any ActiveRecord magic from it (I hope).

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_products(category)
  products = category.products.to_a
  category.subcategories.each do |sub|
    products << get_products(sub)  # Change to products += get_products(sub)
  end
  products
end
```

Thanks to Migol, it solve the recursive issue for me. However, just want to let people know that **products << get_products** means "Inserting the array as an object into the array".

I changed it to **products += get_products**. This actually concat the arrays which I wanted actually.